# Bang! Distances scope

Tags: bang

Does the scope card change the distance at which you can Panic somebody ?
As the Panic card has the symbol "Distance of 1", I'm wondering if the scope changes that. Same question for Rose Doolan who sees everybody at a distance decreased by 1.
And does that apply to the tomahawk card as well ? (which means you could throw it to somebody that is at a distance of 3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, cards like the scope allow you to see everyone as if they where 1 distance closer. This lets you use any card with restricted range to hit someone 1 distance further away then normal. This is great with panic or to let you shoot someone who was just out of range before.

On the other hand cards like mustang increase the distance that other players see you by 1. So if you have a scope and the person next to you has a mustang the two effects would cancel each other out.